# Flag handled wrongly

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flagging, moderation

On [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53153/4732) I had raised a flag trying to draw Mods attention towards it. The answer did not have sources then and that's why I had raised the flag. Till yesterday the flag was pending but today I found that it was declined.

> No sources. – Rickross Oct 11 at 7:11   declined - a moderator
> reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

At present the answer has sources but that was not the case when I had flagged it. It can be checked when I raised the flag and when sources were added to the answer. Then what is the justification for declining my flag?